# How to install and run midnight commander on Busybox?

Tags: installation, busybox

I'm just downloaded busybox image for docker. And it's a bit confusing how to install packages with busybox.
For example, how to install and run midnight commander on busybox?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to confuse busybox as "an OS (or at least a whole userland)".

This is not the case. What Busybox is:

> BusyBox combines tiny versions of many common UNIX utilities into a
>   single small executable. It provides replacements for most of the
>   utilities you usually find in GNU fileutils, shellutils, etc.

Source:
https://www.busybox.net/about.html

The whole utilities/command that Busybox can provide are documented in its "Command help" section, here:

https://www.busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html

*And nothing more.*

(It can then be configured and build to provide *less* than that, since its targeted to FLASH/memory constrained embedded environment and you may want to make busybox smaller).

Notice, in its command help, how it provides close to nothing[0] to manage the installation of other, non-busybox things such as midnight commander. Which does not imply that you *cannot* install and run midnight commander in a busybox-based user environment, only that *its none of busybox business*.

I don't know what's your purpose running a busybox docker image, but you may want to read busybox documentation first.

[0]:
As it is busybox *can* provide a `dpkg` command, to "Install, remove and manage Debian packages". I never used that though.